# Pandas: assign category based on where value falls in range

Tags: python, pandas, categories

I have the following ranges and a pandas DataFrame:

```
x >= 0        # success
-10 <= x < 0  # warning
X < -10       # danger

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2, 1], 'y': [-7, -5], 'z': [-30, -20]})
```

I'd like to categorize the values in the DataFrame based on where they fall within the defined ranges. So I'd like the final DF to look something like this:

```
    x    y    z    x_cat    y_cat    z_cat
0   2   -7  -30  success  warning   danger
1   1   -5  -20  success  warning   danger
```

I've tried using the `category` datatype but it doesn't appear I can define a range anywhere.

```
for category_column, value_column in zip(['x_cat', 'y_cat', 'z_cat'], ['x', 'y', 'z']):
    df[category_column] = df[value_column].astype('category')
```

Can I use the `category` datatype? If not, what can I do here?

Comment: I assume, if a value  of `y` or `z` ist >= 0 (say 5), should it then also be `success`, and it is only by chance that your example of `y` will result in `warning` and `z` in `danger`? If so, it could be worth changing your rule notation to `value >= 0 # success` etc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**`pandas.cut`**

```
c = pd.cut(
    df.stack(),
    [-np.inf, -10, 0, np.inf],
    labels=['danger', 'warning', 'success']
)
df.join(c.unstack().add_suffix('_cat'))

   x  y   z    x_cat    y_cat   z_cat
0  2 -7 -30  success  warning  danger
1  1 -5 -20  success  warning  danger
```

**`numpy`**

```
v = df.values
cats = np.array(['danger', 'warning', 'success'])
code = np.searchsorted([-10, 0], v.ravel()).reshape(v.shape)
cdf = pd.DataFrame(cats[code], df.index, df.columns)
df.join(cdf.add_suffix('_cat'))

   x  y   z    x_cat    y_cat   z_cat
0  2 -7 -30  success  warning  danger
1  1 -5 -20  success  warning  danger
```

Comment: Although, 2nd one worked but need some explanation on it

Comment: which one is faster ? haha

Answer (score 4):

You can use pandas [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), but you need to apply it column by column (just because the function operates on 1-d input):

```
labels = df.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, [-np.inf, -10, 0, np.inf], labels = ['danger', 'warning', 'success']))

          x        y       z
0  success  warning  danger
1  success  warning  danger
```

So you can do:

```
pd.concat([df, labels.add_prefix('_cat')], axis = 1)

   x  y   z     cat_x     cat_y    cat_z
0  2 -7 -30  success  warning  danger
1  1 -5 -20  success  warning  danger
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a little function and then pass each series to the function using apply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [2, 1], 'y': [-7, -5], 'z': [-30, -20]})

def cat(x):
    if x <-10:
        return "Danger"
    if x < 0:
        return "Warning"
    return "Success"

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: cat(x))
```

Comment: None of the answers mentioned above worked for me. except yours. Thansk

Answer (score 3):

you could use assign to make new columns. for each new column use apply to filter the series.

```
df.assign(x_cat = lambda v: v.x.apply(lambda x: 'Sucess' if x>=0 else None),
         y_cat = lambda v: v.y.apply(lambda x: 'warning' if -10<=x<0 else None),
         z_cat = lambda v: v.z.apply(lambda x: 'danger' if x<=-10 else None),)
```

will result in

```
    x   y   z   x_cat   y_cat   z_cat
0   2   -7  -30 Sucess  warning danger
1   1   -5  -20 Sucess  warning danger
```

Comment: If `y` is >=0 you would return `None`, but I expect, the OP would like to have `success` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ternary method for this type of thing.

```
filter_method = lambda x: 'success' if x >= 0 else 'warning' if (x < 0 and x >= -10) else 'danger' if x < -10 else None
df[category_column] = df[value_column].apply(filter_method)
```